# Using Tomcat behind Apache2 Http with different context paths

Tags: apache-2.2, proxy, tomcat, reverse-proxy, ajp

On our Ubuntu webserver we have a Apache2 HTTP server in conjunction with an JSF application running on an Tomcat8 application server using AJP 1.3 connector and HTTPS/SSL. I want my app which runs on localhost:8009/myApp/ to be accessible from  https://subdomain.domain.com (subdomain and domain are palceholders of course). In other words, I want different context paths (/ on apache2, /myApp on tomcat)

Now I'm facing the problem that - althougth the welcome-page is accessible - all resources/images/links are broken as they still contain the context path /myApp. I've tried to set up corresponding ProxPass/ReverseProxyPass settings without success.

```
<VirtualHost _default_:443>
        ServerAdmin admin@domain.com
        DocumentRoot /srv/www/subdomain.domain.com
        ServerName subdomain.domain.com

        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^subdomain\.domain\.com$ [NC]
        RewriteRule .? https://subdomain.domain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

        <Location />
                ProxyPass ajp://localhost:8009/myApp/ connectiontimeout=5 timeout=300
                ProxyPassReverse https://localhost:8080/myApp/
                ProxyPassReverse https://subdomain.domain.com/myApp/
                ProxyPassReverse ajp://localhost:8009/myApp/
                ProxyPassReverseCookiePath /myApp/ /

                #Order deny,allow
                Allow from all
        </Location>

</VirtualHost>
```

PS: As a workaround, myApp currently runs on the root-context "/" on tomcat, but I want to change that to accomondate multiple web apps.

In tomcat's conf/server.xml I have the following connector configured:

```
<!-- Define an AJP 1.3 Connector on port 8009 -->
<Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443"
           address="127.0.0.1"
           proxyName="subdomain.domain.com" proxyPort="443" secure="true" />
```

Comment: can u tell us what is images source link displayed in browser (while it is broken) ?

Comment: @Froggiz an images referrs to e.g. <img src="/myApp/resources/images/logo.png" height="40">

Comment: so why not try to proxy https://localhost:8080/ instead of https://localhost:8080/MyApp ? or rewrite /MyApp/ to / ?

Comment: because my app is not running on  localhost:8080 (or maybe I don't understand your comment).

Comment: to test if your images (and other extar content) works using https://subdomain.domain.com/MyApp/

Answer (score 0):

you could try to add this rewrite condition:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/myApp/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/myApp(.*) https://subdomain.domain.com$1 [R=301,L]
```

like that your extra stuff should have correct link :

`https://localhost:8080/myApp/` intead of `https://localhost:8080/myApp/myApp/`

Comment: images are shown correctly, but other issues seem to arise (redirection etc) now...

Comment: can you please add more infos, i am not sure to understand